# Batch Script-Powershell MessageBox | How do I set TopMost within PS command line of Batch?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, messagebox, windows-scripting

I created a single file to run a set of backup commands for a proprietary software that needs to run in Windows Vista thru Windows 10.

However, I am having an issue where the PS MessageBox keeps getting hidden under the CMD and PS Windows that pop-up. I know there should be a way to set the MessageBox to TopMost within the PS -Command line I am using within the batch file.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a good way of doing so without creating separate PS files which is not something I can do as I need this to be a single file that can be remotely transferred to multiple systems in multiple corp. environments, used by multiple agents who may not have any IT experience. This is what I am currently using that keeps getting hidden by other open windows.

```
powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Message', 'Title of MessageBox', 'Button', [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information);}"

powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic; [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Message', 'Title of InputBox')}" > %TEMP%\out.tmp
```

Can anyone assist with adding the TopMost=True statement to this command line?

Comment: Try with `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly`: `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Message', 'Title of MessageBox', [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions]::DefaultDesktopOnly)`

Comment: The linked duplicate shows two solution options; one of them is the one Mathias mentioned. As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was a simple way to do this, this did work, oddly enough just sticking it on the first was enough to get the others to pop-up correctly as well. 

powershell -Command "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Message', 'TitleOfMessageBox', [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions]::DefaultDesktopOnly);}"